# wp_list_pages sort order by custom nav menu order

Tags: menus, pages, sitemap

Does anyone know of a way to create a sitemap by using wp_list_pages and have the order by the same orders a custom nav menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) you can sort order only by:

- 'post_title'
- 'menu_order'
- 'post_date'
- 'post_modified'
- 'ID'
- 'post_author'
- 'post_name'

anything else (like order by custom menu order) you would have to write your own function.
But a better way to get it done would be to create a custom walker for it so you could control the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I use to create a sitemap based on custom menu order:
http://snipplr.com/view/54404/wordpress-custom-sitemap-shortcode-following-custom-menu-order/